# What's the best way to order list of countries in French from a usability standpoint?

Tags: localization, internationalization, usability

I have a list of countries that I would like to display in a dropdown menu. Now, because of their french translations, the list either needs to be re-ordered, or countries need to be rewritten.

For example, `Canary Islands` is translated into `Îles Canaries` in french. Should I re-order the list so that all `Îles` are grouped togheter? Or should I write it as `Canaries, Îles`. Additionally, will people be able to navigate to `Îles` by typing the accented `Î`?

Comment: What gives you the idea to re-order it (e.g., as "Canaries, Îles")?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you go for "Canaries, Îles"? Just to keep the English order?
Imagine that an English list would have that as "Islands, Canary"

- Translate the way a native would expect it (in French)
- Sort it following the French rules
- Find it when the user types Î, and I

In general internationalisation is not hard: just turn the table and think what would you want if a German or French software is translated into English.

Comment: "Translate the way a native would expect it" is kinda my question :)

Comment: And the answer is kind of there already: "Canary Islands is translated into Îles Canaries in french" :-) They translate it the way they expect it :-)

Comment: And you can search for beginning of words, not of the full string. So typing "is" in English will find both Canary Islands, and Israel. But it is not a substring match, so don't find Tunisia. Might even be even more helpful and search for abbreviated or alternate forms that you keep as hidden info. For instance EEUU as Spanish abbreviation for Estados Unidos (United States)

Answer (score 1):

I agree it should be Isles first - stick with how someone would say the name. For example United States is Etas-Unis - or States United - but you wouldn't reverse the order to match English convention.